# How to find pulse width and repetition rates of proton beam using TOF?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, spectroscopy

Having parameter such as flight path, charge(q), mass and energy. How do I find the repetition rates and the pulse width?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Pulse width and repetition rate are machine parameters. They have nothing to do with proton mass, charge and energy. Within a certain range those parameters can be adjusted and in modern accelerators the bunch structure can become quite complex. Are you asking about beam diagnostics? There are a variety of methods how one can detect and characterize particle beams. Which one one would use depends on the detailed beam parameters and use case.

Comment: For a pulsing unit, repetition rates and pulse width is needed. So, to determine these values, the Time Of Flight(TOF) method have to be adopted (or is there another method to find it)?.